# Encriptar contraseñde conexion a la base de datos en Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3, virtualhost, md5

Es posible encriptar la contraseña que tipeo en texto plano para conectarme con la bases de datos que utilizo en codeigniter? En el Archivo aplication/config/database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
 $query_builder = TRUE;

 $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'mi_password',
    'database' => 'xx_database',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

O sea el 'password' => 'mi_password'????

Comment: Sugiero leer https://goo.gl/FH1apb, te será muy util para este tema, lo que tendrías que hacer es colocar tu password encriptado en un archivo y luego en el archivo database.php llamar una funcion que te retorne el password desecriptado, obviamente esta funcion tendrías que desarrollarla tu mismo, donde consideres desde donde cargas el archivo, que parametros de encripcion utilizar, etc, etc. Debes tener en cuenta que esto a la final realmente no es un medida fuerte de seguridad para tu contraseña, pues otro programador podrá entender lo que hiciste y eventualmente obtener ese password.

Comment: aparte, no olvides el certificado de seguridad en tu servidor, para que cuando mandes por post tu password viaje por https. Luego como te dice Jonnathan guardar en bbdd tu password encriptado.

Comment: ese es el problema que cualquier otro programador puede perfectamente saber cual es aun cuando le haya creado un metodo para eso. Solo necesitaria tempo y paciencia para buscarlo. No hay alguna forma para encriptar esa contraseña, mediante md5 o hash no se???

Comment: Como pudiera encriptar esa conexion entonces???